# Is it possible to have a stable ternary star system?

Tags: space, stars, orbital-mechanics

I was thinking, and I came up with an idea. Have three stars of equal mass orbiting a single point, with all stars in the same plane. But is there any way to make this possible? If not, is there a way to make three stars of equal mass have a stable system?

Comment: 3 points are always on the same plane. They will circle around their barycentre which will be on the same plane.

Comment: @Frostfyre definitely a duplicate. It answers the question, planet optional